# How to keep user location centered after mapview is moved

Tags: ios, swift, animation, mapkit

I have a mapview thats half the size of the screen and when a uialert action is triggered, the view is moved to the other half of the screen but user location loses its center point on the map.

Here is what I do:

```
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
        (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionCurlUp, animations: {
            self.mapview.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.0, y: -334.0)
        }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

On completion set mapview.center to the value you need